# Can't load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, nib, nsbundle

I understand that there are other questions very similar to this one that have been asked, but nothing out there seems to help me.

I'm including a library via cocoapods that has a resource bundle with a .xib file in it. When I call a method from that library this gets called:

```
dispatch_once(&pred,
              ^{
                  NSBundle *posBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClipPOSLibrary" ofType:@"bundle"]];
                  sharedInstance = (POSReaderAlert*)[posBundle loadNibNamed:@"POSReaderAlert" owner:self options:nil][0];
                  sharedInstance.yCenterOffsetPercentage = 0;
                  sharedInstance.batteryThresholds = @[@(1), @(5), @(10), @(20)];
                  sharedInstance.currentThreshold = 3;
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:sharedInstance
                                                           selector:@selector(handleRotation:)
                                                               name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                                             object:nil];
              });
```

I get a thrown exception on the 'sharedInstance = (POSReder.....' line. This is the exception:

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F41CE11A-1E7A-4902-83F2-285CC2508D41/EMV-Flow-Example.app/ClipPOSLibrary.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'POSReaderAlert'
```

I've made sure that when the library is built, the nib has the correct target selected, and it's included everywhere it needs to be. The strange thing is that I don't always get this error. I've built projects with the same library and everything seems to work fine, but in other projects it doesn't. So my guess is that there's something I'm doing wrong in the project configuration/settings but I really can't figure out what.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

*** update ***
So I got the issue to go away for iOS 6 and 7 by fixing the target setting to use a good xcconfig file, which needed to be done because the workspace is a little wonky with three different projects inside of it. But the problem is still happening on iOS 8. Any ideas?